# Delete Duplicates from joining a table which has arbitrary decimal values

Tags: output-formatting, table

Let's say we have two tables that have entries with arbitrary decimals. I joined them using Join and now I want to use DeleteDuplicates to delete the duplicates which have the same numbers till 5 decimal points. How can I do that?

Comment: **How can I do that?** could you provide an example to use? One way might be to use Round on the numbers first to round them to 5 decimal points, then use DeleteDuplicates after that? But need an example of your input to try this on first.

Comment: Or instead of Round, may be Chop is what is needed. Chop takes second argument delta which can be used for this.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = RandomReal[{0, 0.0001}, 100];

DeleteDuplicates[data, Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-5 &]

(* {0.0000447438, 0.0000868851, 
 8.09452*10^-6, 0.0000764421, 0.0000279434, 0.0000593133, 
 0.000098101} *)

Union[data, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-5 &)]

(* {1.91036*10^-6, 0.0000130352, 0.0000230656, 0.0000343098, 
    0.0000447438, 0.0000552897, 0.0000690272, 0.0000792503, 
    0.0000893103} *)

DeleteDuplicates[Round[data, 10.^-5]]

(* {0.00004, 0.00009, 0.00001, 0.00008, 0.00007, 0.00005, 0.00003, 
    0.00006, 0.0001, 0.00002, 0.} *)

Union[Round[data, 10.^-5]]

(* {0., 0.00001, 0.00002, 0.00003, 0.00004, 0.00005, 0.00006, 
0.00007, 0.00008, 0.00009, 0.0001} *)
```